# Dynamic generated excel has large size in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datatable that fetches around 75K records from database and export the same to excel in ASP.Net. Records are fetching fast, but exporting is the problem. It is taking a huge amount of time to export, and once exported, the file size will become double or triple. When I copy paste the same data to new excel and check the size, it becomes much lower. So for e.g: while generating it's 37 MB, and after generated and copy paste to new excel, it becomes 9 MB. I am not sure how the size got drastically reduced after copy paste.

Following is the code I have tried.

```
void CreateExcelFile()
{
    using (DataTable dt = dset().Tables[0])
    {
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string filename = "STATUSREPORT.xls";
            System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
            GridView dgGrid = new GridView();
            dgGrid.DataSource = dt;
            dgGrid.DataBind();
            dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
            this.EnableViewState = false;
            Response.Write(tw.ToString());
            Response.End();
        }
        else
        {
            string ky = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), ky, "showalert('" + 0 + "','There is no data in this criteria, change the criteria and try again');", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/epplus/drafts/98280) for example. All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension.

Comment: Thanks Manfred. I used EPPLus, seems to be working for me. Let me test it for sometime, but hopefully it works. Thanks  a lot.